# __weak self not working as expected

Tags: ios

I have the following code:

```
    __weak id weakSelf = self;
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    if(error)
        NSLog(@"Geocoder failed with error: %@", error);
    else
        weakSelf.placeMark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];



            }];
    NSLog(@"current placemark: %@", self.placeMark);

}
```

the reason I want to use a weak self, its because I saw this in another example when I was researching why "Xcode couldn't find" my properties by self.some_property inside this block. Anyway, I now receive error msg that placeMark is not a member of weakSelf. placeMark is declared as a strong, nonatomic property. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to cast your variable because here you just have an (id), so Xcode doesn't recognize the custom properties of your instance

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 __weak typeof(<self class name>) weakSelf = self;
```

it is a proper way to create your weakSelf object to use in the block

you can also create another class object to use in the block like

```
__weak typeof(A) weakA = self;
__weak typeof(B) weakB = objB;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure on the object type then replace `id` with the actual object type here. Something like this:

```
__weak MyClass weakSelf = self;
```

Now, you can directly access properties like `placeMark` on `MyClass`.